# In C what does this macro define?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, bit-shift

```
#define NUM_SQ_0 (1 << 1*1)  //<<----- ??

static struct square sq_0[NUM_SQ_0];
```

Note that square is a struct with 4 pointers to square, defined as follows:

```
typedef struct square {
    struct square *nw, *ne,
                  *sw, *se;
} *square;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per C++ operator precedence, the `*` operator is evaluated first, and that evaluates to the value `1`, and then it's shifted one bit to the left, which is the value `2^1` or just `2`.

Comment: Accepted because you explained the operator precedence. Thanx

Answer (score 7):

It evaluates to a 1 shifted 1 bit to the left, i.e. the number also known as 2.

Since the multiplication operator `*` binds tighter than the bit-shifting operator `<<`, the expression is parsed as `1 << (1 * 1)`, i.e. just `1 << 1`.

In binary, using 8 bits for readability, we have

```
  00000001
<<       1        
==========
  00000010
```

Converting back to decimal, we get 00000010<sub>2</sub> = 2<sub>10</sub>.

Answer (score 2):

`1 << 1*1` simply evaluates to `2`
From the name of the macro and the struct later, one could imagine that there are multiple arrays of different sizes, that are calculated as a series of bit-shifts by a multiple of numbers... e.g. have a `NUM_SQ_1 (1 << 2*2)`... but this is just guessing...

Comment: You guessed correctly, further down in the code is `NUM_SQ_1 (1 << 2*2)`

Answer (score 0):

One, shifted left by one bit. This will result in two. I can't imagine the rationale for this macro.

Answer (score 0):

`1 << 1*1` [shifts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f96c63ed%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) `0x01` left by 1 bit, which evaluates to `0x02`. So `NUM_SQ_0` equals 2 and `sq_0` is an array of two `square` structs.

E.g. its the same as `static struct square sq_0[2];`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an oddly roundabout way to say:

```
#define NUM_SQ_0 2
```

Perhaps the intent was to eventually replace one (or both) terms in 1*1 by another macro as a sort of compile-time parameter but was never documented and eventually forgotten. Unfortunately, this sort of thing happens all too often.